# Disable online event link when create an event on a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, validation, events

When creating a new event on a sharepoint site, the user is forced to provide 'Online meeting link'.

Is it possible to make it optional. I can't seem to be able to save the event unless this field is populated.

Thanks

Edit:

Below is the screenshot of the web part I'm talking about. I have found 'Event' in the Site Content Types and removed the 'Location' itam. In fact, I've also removed the Category column from the Event. I've saved it and chose 'Update all content types inheriting from this type?' as Yes. Yet, when I try to create a new event, both the Location and Category still appear.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the OOTB SharePoint Online "Events" webpart/list to add the events? Have you tried to make the column optional from content type settings?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the OOB Events web part, the page to create new event from the "Add event” button is `_layouts/15/Event.aspx` and does not support customization.
These are built-in controls on this modern page and cannot be modified or removed.

Removing the columns from the Event content type will not have influence on this page or the Event list.

In fact, all these event properties are **optional** except for **Title** field. Also quoting the document: [Use the Events web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-events-web-part-5fe4da93-5fa9-4695-b1ee-b0ae4c981909):

> If you don't have an online meeting and enter nothing, this section
> will not appear in the event.

It will not force the user to enter a link or return error when saving with this field empty.

Comment: Thanks. I've just rechecked it and not sure how it happened but, as you said, it lets me save it. I'm not sure what happened. It might have been something to do with permissions.